# Инициализировать массив в javascript полученный из json

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

Передаю в json массив данных

```
public void treatmentElementsPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String[] arr = request.getParameterValues("dcsel");
        try {
            JSONResponse.sendJSONRequest(request,response,arr);     
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Syslog.error(this, "Ошибка при отправке JSON ответа:" + e);
        }
    }
```

Получаю его в js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    enableLoadAnimation();
    $("#ds").submit(function(e) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : defaultPath+'reports/treatmentElementsPage',
            cache : false,
            processData : false,
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

Как мне пройтись по всем элементам в полученном массиве?
Данный массив - это выпадающий список значений на странице.
данная js страница вызывается в jsp.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: defaultPath+'reports/treatmentElementsPage',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(index, item) {
            console.log(item);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно так использую

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/index.php?somequery',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: fdata,
                success: function (json) {


                    if (json.error) {
                        for (var prop in json.error) {
                            // prop - это ключ в json.error
                            // чтобы получить значение можно использовать json.error[prop]
                        }
                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
```